# How to stop a div from automatically scrolling to bottom

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello everyone i have been looking for a code to stop a section in a P.O.S from jumping to the bottom when i scroll up to the top. I have tried a few variations of a Javascript code but most i can get it to do is jump back down but a few lines from the end of the divider. Here is the code i started with that goes right to the bottom. This does it when it refeshes the div every 2 seconds.

```
function at_Ticket_ScrollBottom()
{
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("cartTicket");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

The second code I used is:

```
function at_Ticket_ScrollBottom()
{
   var objDiv = document.getElementById("cartTicket");
   objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.offsetHeight;
}
```

This second code jumps down but is a few lines from the bottom. I am trying to make it so it will remain on the line you highlight no matter what one in the div it is.

I am using PHP, Javascript, and ajax for this web based point of sales system. if you have any ideas that would be great been struggling for about a week and the closest I got is the second code I posted. Most people ask how to auto scroll to the bottom so I haven't find a lot so far